# Proof Solver Geometry

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, automated-theorem-proving, computer-assisted-proofs

Are there any programs that can solve Geometry Problems?

An example of such a problem would be:
The centroid of a triangle always divides its medians into two sections with a 1:2 ratio.

While that problem is very easy to solve by hand, I am wondering whether it can be automated in any way.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Recall that [Euclidean geometry is decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms), meaning that every geometric theorem has a proof or dis-proof. By having a computer program checking over every string of letters and symbols, and halt on a string if that string is a proof or dis-proof, you'd have such a computer program. QED.

Comment: @Alejandro Bergasa Alonso Software "assistants" for geometrical proofs is an active field of research. See for example one of them based on the exceptional Coq language:  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228381534_A_Combination_of_a_Dynamic_Geometry_Software_With_a_Proof_Assistant_for_Interactive_Formal_Proofs

Comment: I added an answer as a community wiki, so people can complete the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several such programs:

- Geometry Expert: http://www.mmrc.iss.ac.cn/gex/
- Java Geometry Expert: https://github.com/yezheng1981/Java-Geometry-Expert
- GCLC: [http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~janicic/gclc/](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/%7Ejanicic/gclc/)
- GeoTher: [https://www-polsys.lip6.fr/~wang/](https://www-polsys.lip6.fr/%7Ewang/)
- Implementation of theorem proving inside GeoGebra (http://www.geogebra.org) and its experimental version GeoGebra Discovery (https://github.com/kovzol/geogebra-discovery)
- Implementation of the area method in Coq: https://github.com/coq-contribs/area-method
- A library of examples with automatic proofs: http://hilbert.mat.uc.pt/TGTP/index.php, http://hilbert.mat.uc.pt/GeoThms/

An overview of the different methods and implementations can be found in our chapter:

- Julien Narboux, Predrag Janičić and Jacques Fleuriot. Computer-assisted Theorem Proving in Synthetic Geometry. Meera Sitharam; Audrey St. John; Jessica Sidman. Handbook of Geometric Constraint Systems Principles, Chapman and Hall/CRC, In press, Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 1498738915. ⟨hal-01779452⟩

An overview of the implementation in GeoGebra can be found here:

- Francisco Botana, Markus Hohenwarter, Predrag Janičić, Zoltán Kovács, Ivan Petrović, Tomás Recio and Simon Weitzhofer.
  [Automated Theorem Proving in GeoGebra: Current Achievements](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277353909_Automated_Theorem_Proving_in_GeoGebra_Current_Achievements).
  Journal of Automated Reasoning volume 55, pages 39–59 (2015)

and a more recent publication on the same program is here:

- Z. Kovács, Tomás Recio, M. Pilar Vélez: Using Automated Reasoning Tools in GeoGebra in the Teaching and Learning of Proving in Geometry. International Journal of Technology in Mathematic Education. Vol. 25, no. 2. pp. 33-50. 2018.  (https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/188016037.pdf)

or here:

- Francisco Botana, Zoltán Kovács, Tomás Recio: A mechanical geometer. Mathematics in Computer Science, online Nov. 20, 2020.  https://doi.org/10.1007/s11786-020-00497-7

Answer (score 0):

With GeoGebra Discovery you can even ask GeoGebra for the relation of the two segments that the centroid produces in the median.
[image: Problem setting in GeoGebra Discovery]
The Relation tool "guesses" (but rigorously), and it is 2:1.

First, only numerically:
[image: Numerical check]

Then, the symbolic relation is shown:
[image: Symbolic relation]

Finally, if you do not need to "guess" the relation and you know it already, you can use directly the **Prove** command in GeoGebra (see the bottom of the picture: **d=Prove(2k==j)** and the answer is true...
[image: Output of the Prove command in GeoGebra]

The proof is algebraic geometry based, so it is not readable.